# SQL query to get count of last 7 day data into 24 hour format

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate count of record in last 24 hours and then 24 to 48 hours and 48 to 72 hours and so on up to 120 hours.

I wrote this query but it works to fetch 1 day's details only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.UPDATED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY table_column
```

I need result like this:

| count | column | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | abc | 0-24 |
| 32 | abc | 24-48 |
| 9 | abc | 48-72 |

Comment: Please clarify the question because the title and description doesn't match. Which dbms are you really using ?  If possible please add some data example and expected result in text format.

Comment: Please do not spam lots of RDBMS tags. Please [edit] the answer and only include tag for the one that you are using.

Comment: @ErgestBasha can you check again

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement as follow (this works on MySQL):

```
select count(your_column_name) as cnt,      
       case 
            when UPDATED_TIME >  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  then '0-24' 
            when UPDATED_TIME <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  and UPDATED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR) then '24-48'
            when UPDATED_TIME <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)  and UPDATED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR) then '48-72'
       end as time
from table_name
group by time;
```

*Note*. Use CURDATE() if you have only the date format like `2022-06-24` otherwise use NOW();.

If you have other date ranges you could add another condition  `else 72+`.

```
select count(your_column_name) as cnt,      
       case 
            when UPDATED_TIME >  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  then '0-24' 
            when UPDATED_TIME <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  and UPDATED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR) then '24-48'
            when UPDATED_TIME <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)  and UPDATED_TIME > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR) then '48-72'
            else '72+'
       end as time
from table_name
group by time;
```